# MySQL Search in Range

Tags: mysql, split, range

I have the column where range values are stored with space between them, for example:

> 0 10003 [range between 0 and 10003]
>
> 0 1000003 [range between 0 and 1000003]
>
> 20 5000 [range between 20 and 5000]

I have a search form with two inputs: from and to, and I need to select results that are in the specified range.

I know about `SPLIT_STR` function, but is there a better way? I need to bulid a `WHERE` clause for this task.

Comment: You need to normalize the table. Whoever designed this is a moron.

Comment: I know, but I can't optimize it, because the data comes from third-party provider.

Comment: Tell your third-party provider to learn how to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE FROM = (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(COLVALUE, ' ', 1))
AND TO = (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(COLVALUE, ' ', -1));
```

Hope this helps you.